# How to Install Richoh MPC 5000 TWAIN Driver

Tags: windows-7, drivers, multi-function-printer, twain

I am running Windows 7; am connected by TCP/IP port to a Ricoh MPC 5000; and can print.

I've downloaded the TWAIN driver for the MPC 5000. Neither a setup.exe nor a .msi file exist in the download directory disk1. I've looked at the readme.txt file, and it only mentions installing a printer.

I need help installing the TWAIN drivers.

Comment: You'll need to add new hardware...choose the type of hardware...when it asks for a driver give it the one you downloaded.

Comment: Thanks. If you put how to reach add hardware wizard, I'll accept your answer. It would have worked, except Windows 7 doesn't like the printer.inf downloaded.

Comment: Did you use the correct version? Do you know if you have a 32-bit or 64-bit installation of Windows?